# Zend studio remote system resource dose not exist?

Tags: php, zend-studio

I use remote system to synchronize the project in linux to the local by an option called Create Remote Project. anybody who used this?why it gives such an error!!
Only one or two files can't be opened,The reason is that I open the Zend Studio before I open the linux virtual machine.
but how to resolve the problem?
by the way i wonder PHPers usually use what to coding a project on linux of(virtal machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the file you can not open is being used in another progress. you can restart your Zend and have a look